# Collection / map that supports order, inserts, and lookup by both index and key

Tags: java, android, date, arraylist, dictionary

In Java (Android), I have a bunch of records that are keyed by unique dates.  They are also sorted based on increasing date. The user is meant to add to this collection.

I need to do be able to do the following:

1. Lookup these records directly by date
2. Lookup these records directly by index
3. Insert a new record (with unique date) anywhere, including between two existing records, and thus, adjusting the indexes of all affected records.

Some implementation details --

These records will be sorted in increasing order by date (newest at the end).

These records will also be displayed in reverse-order (newest date at the top) in an Android ListView, thus non-linear, direct access to the index is required.

These records will also be plotted based on a date that may or may not exist in the database, thus direct lookup by date is required.

I haven't been able to find an existing solution that addresses these requirements.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just wrap a `TreeMap` into a class of yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an existing collection for this. I would use a TreeMap for the records:

```
Map<Date, MyRecord> records = new TreeMap<Date, MyRecord>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Whenever you want to add to the map, or lookup by date, just use the map in the usual way.

However, I don't think you actually need a look-up by index method in order to display your records in a `ListView` with newest on top. All you need is a `List<MyRecord>` and an `ArrayAdapter` instantiated using

```
new ArrayAdapter(context, resourceId, list);
```

Whenever the `ListView` needs to be updated use the code:

```
list.clear();
list.addAll(records.values());  // Because records is a TreeMap, values() will be in correct order.
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```